# Saving a string in python associated with an API

Tags: python, bitcoin

it is my first post on stackoverflow so please go easy on me! :) I am also relatively new to python so bear with me :)

With all that said here is my issue: I am writing a bit of code for fun which calls an API and grabs the latest Bitcoin Nonce data. I have managed to do this fine, however now I want to be able to save the first nonce value found as a string such as Nonce1 and then recall the API every few seconds till I get another Nonce value and name it Nonce2 for example? Is this possible? My code is down bellow.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import blocktrail

client = blocktrail.APIClient(api_key="x", api_secret="x", network="BTC", testnet=False)
address = client.address('x')

latest_block = client.block_latest()

nonce = latest_block['nonce']

print(nonce)

noncestr = str(nonce)
```

Thanks, again please go easy on me I am very new to Python :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple-minded solution:

```
import time
nonce = "some string"
while True:
  latest_nonce = client.block_latest()['nonce']
  if latest_nonce != nonce:
     nonce = latest_nonce
  time.sleep(2)
```

Ideally you should use something like asyncio for unblocking execution.

Comment: Just quickly what do you mean by unblocking execution?

Comment: @Joshua I mean you could spin off a new thread to check the API periodically while executing other code in the main thread. Upvote if you find this answer useful :)

Comment: Okay thanks, this is pretty complex for me however I will give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list and add your nonces to it:

```
nonces = []
nonces.append(yournonce)
```

Then you can access them like so:

```
nonces[noncenum]
```

You could use a while loop and `time.sleep` to get a new nonce every few seconds.

Comment: Okay after running the code using a list I found that all I get is a replacement of the original nonce value inside the list. As all I am doing is re running the code and just replacing the old nonce value with the new one found from the API. I never actually get a new nonce value added, perhaps I am doing something wrong?